# Zookeeper - Due Date for Log4J Upgrade

Tags: log4j, apache-zookeeper

Log4J version (1.x) used by Apache Zookeeper exposes users to the following CVE-s:

Critical -

1. [CVE-2019-17571](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571)
2. [CVE-2022-23305](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23305)
3. [CVE-2022-23307](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23307)

High -

1. [CVE-2022-23302](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23302)
2. [CVE-2021-4104](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4104)

Low -

1. [CVE-2020-9488](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-9488)

When (on which release) will Zookeeper be upgraded to the latest Log4J release?
is there a workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: Version 3.8.0 published 3 weeks ago uses Logback... Can you clarify your question? Do you want to get rid of Log4j 1.x or to use Log4j 2.x with Zookeeper?

Comment: The motivation is to remove CVE exposure ASAP either by switching Zookeeper to the latest Log4j 2.X or by entirely removing Log4J.